# How to save multiple entities FK to single attribute in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have object Car with nested object User that can not be null.

```
class Car {
    @Id
    int id;
    @NotNull
    User user;
}
```

But I would like to upgrade Vehicle to also have option of being owned by Company. Car can not be owned by both at the same time. Is there an option in Hibernate to have FK in Car that can be used as User and Company? Here is example:

```
class Car {
    @Id
    int id;
    @NotNull
    Owner owner; //Can be object type User or Comapny
}
```

I have idea to make extra object UserRole which would have option to nest User and Company, but I'm searching for better solution/optimization that won't require extra object if it is possible in Hibernate:

```
class Car {
    @Id
    int id;
    @NotNull
    UserRole owner; //Can be object type User or Comapny
}
class UserRole{
    @Id
    int id; // PK, that will be used in Car
    User user;
    Company company;
    int type; // determinates what if owner is User or Company
}
```

Implementation will be used to store entites on API.
Please suggest it there is easier way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're saying that `User` is not nullable. Then you say that `Car` cannot be owned by both `User` and `Company` at the same time - means `User` is nullable.

You can't use the same field to both `Company` and `User`. In Hibernate each class is associated with a single entity. So my suggestion is to do

```
class Car {
    @Id
    int id;

    @ManyToOne
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    Company company;
}
```

without the `@NotNull` annotation, and then just check if null or not.

Second option is to use inheritance (if possible). you can create a `@MappedSuperClass` called `CarHolder` and then make `User` and `Owner` inherit from it. then you can hold just one field of `CarHolder` inside Car.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them:

```
class Car {
    @Id
    int id;
    @NotNull
    User user;
    @NotNull
    Company company;
}
```

And just checks the `user` property and the `company` property for `null` when you need to get an owner of a car.